# vue.config.js into quasar.config.js

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework

I'd like to use the the following vue.config.js with Quasar:

```
module.exports = {
    publicPath:
      process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
        ? "/static/dist/"
        : "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
    outputDir: "../../static/dist",
    indexPath: "../../../templates/index.html",
    pages: {
      index: {
        entry: "src/main.js",
        title: "QuestionTime",
      },
    },
    devServer: {
      devMiddleware: {
        publicPath: "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
        writeToDisk: (filePath) => filePath.endsWith("index.html"),
      },
      hot: "only",
      headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" },
    },
  };
```

I'd like to have the index.html file generated by the writeToDisk module.
I've updated the quasar.conf.js, but the index.html is not generated:

```
module.exports = configure(function (ctx) {
  return {
    publicPath:
      process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
        ? "/static/dist/"
        : "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
    outputDir: "../../../static/dist",
    indexPath: "../../../templates/index.html",
    pages: {
      index: {
        entry: "src/main.js",
        title: "QuestionTime",
      },
    },
    // https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/supporting-ts
    supportTS: false,

    // https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/prefetch-feature
    // preFetch: true,

    // app boot file (/src/boot)
    // --> boot files are part of "main.js"
    // https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/boot-files
    boot: [
      
      'axios',
    ],

    // https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/quasar-config-js#Property%3A-css
    css: [
      'app.scss'
    ],

    // https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/tree/dev/extras
    extras: [
      // 'ionicons-v4',
      // 'mdi-v5',
      // 'fontawesome-v6',
      // 'eva-icons',
      // 'themify',
      // 'line-awesome',
      // 'roboto-font-latin-ext', // this or either 'roboto-font', NEVER both!

      'roboto-font', // optional, you are not bound to it
      'material-icons', // optional, you are not bound to it
    ],

    // Full list of options: https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/quasar-config-js#Property%3A-build
    build: {
      vueRouterMode: 'hash', // available values: 'hash', 'history'

      // transpile: false,
      // publicPath: '/',

      // Add dependencies for transpiling with Babel (Array of string/regex)
      // (from node_modules, which are by default not transpiled).
      // Applies only if "transpile" is set to true.
      // transpileDependencies: [],

      // rtl: true, // https://quasar.dev/options/rtl-support
      // preloadChunks: true,
      // showProgress: false,
      // gzip: true,
      // analyze: true,

      // Options below are automatically set depending on the env, set them if you want to override
      // extractCSS: false,

      // https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/handling-webpack
      // "chain" is a webpack-chain object https://github.com/neutrinojs/webpack-chain
      
      chainWebpack (chain) {
        chain.plugin('eslint-webpack-plugin')
          .use(ESLintPlugin, [{ extensions: [ 'js', 'vue' ] }])
      }
      
    },
```

...

Pkg quasar... v2.9.2

Pkg @quasar/app-webpack... v3.6.1

Pkg webpack... v5

I' running Quasar with webpack. I there anything I missed / to take care of?